# Rails ajax: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to rewrite some actions in my app with ajax.

items_controller:

```
...
def add_to_cart
  @cart = Cart.where(id: session[:cart_id]).first
  @cart = Cart.create if @cart.nil?
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  session[:cart_items] = @cart.items
  session[:cart_items] << @item
  redirect_to root_url
end
...
```

items.js:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".addtoCart").click( function() {
    var current_item = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    if(confirm("Add to cart")) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/items/' + $(current_item).attr('data-item-id') + '/add_to_cart',
        type: 'POST'
      });
    };
  });
});
```

view file:

```
%tr{"data-item-id" => "#{i.id}"}
  %td
    %span.addtoCart Add to cart
```

routes:

```
Store::Application.routes.draw do

  root 'items#index'

  resources :items

  resources :items do
    get :add_to_cart, on: :member
  end

end
```

When I click on `Add to cart` there is an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` and `POST http://localhost:3000/items/13/add_to_cart 404 (Not Found)` although `/items/13` is exists. Where did I made a mistake?

error stacktrace:

```
Started POST "/items/13/add_to_cart" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-30 02:55:03 +0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/items/13/add_to_cart")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the the defined `routes`. Also, share the full stacktrace of error.

Comment: You forgot to add the full stacktrace of error.

Comment: @KirtiThorat added stacktrace (not sure I understood clearly what you meant) from Dev Tools of browser

Comment: Not this stacktrace, the one you get in server log stating `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)......`

Comment: @KirtiThorat sorry, edited

Comment: Thats alright. I found your issue, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your routes as below:

```
  root 'items#index'

  resources :items do
    post :add_to_cart, on: :member
  end
```

I converted the `add_to_cart` request to a `post` rather than `get` because you are firing a `post` request and have defined the route as `get`.
Also, I removed the duplicate route defined `resources :items` and